# Reclassify raster MemoryError: Unable to allocate 97.5 GiB for an array with shape (6546455295, 2) and data type int64

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, numpy

I have tried to reclassify my global land use dataset downloaded from [here](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php). And I tried to reclassify this tiff file using the following code.

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
file = gdal.Open('C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.tif')
band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
lista = band.ReadAsArray()


lista[np.where(( 10 <= lista ) & (lista <= 40))] = 1 #Agriculture
lista[np.where(( 50 <= lista) & (lista <= 100)) ] = 2 #Grass land
lista[np.where((110 <= lista) & (lista <= 180)) ] = 3 #Cultivation
lista[np.where(lista == 190)] = 4 #Urban
lista[np.where((191 <= lista) & (lista <= 209)) ] = 0 #Bare land
lista[np.where(210 <= lista) ] = 5 #Water bodies

band.SetNoDataValue(0)

# create new file
file2 = driver.Create( 'reclassify_test_1.tif', file.RasterXSize , file.RasterYSize , 1)
print("file creation finished")

file2.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(lista)

# spatial ref system
proj = file.GetProjection()
georef = file.GetGeoTransform()
file2.SetProjection(proj)
print(proj, 'proj')
file2.SetGeoTransform(georef)
file2.FlushCache()
```

But the error is coming from `lista[np.where(210 <= lista) ] = 5 #Water bodies`. After searching on StackOverflow, I this it is the RAM issue. So my question is, how can I solve this error? Any suggestion?

Here is the gdalinfo report of my dataset,

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.tif
Size is 129600, 64800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.002777777777778,-0.002777777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#bounds=lat_bounds
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lat#valid_max=90
  lat#valid_min=-90
  lccs_class#ancillary_variables=processed_flag current_pixel_state observation_count change_count
  lccs_class#flag_colors=#ffff64 #ffff64 #ffff00 #aaf0f0 #dcf064 #c8c864 #006400 #00a000 #00a000 #aac800 #003c00 #003c00 #005000 #285000 #285000 #286400 #788200 #8ca000 #be9600 #966400 #966400 #966400 #ffb432 #ffdcd2 #ffebaf #ffc864 #ffd278 #ffebaf #00785a #009678 #00dc82 #c31400 #fff5d7 #dcdcdc #fff5d7 #0046c8 #ffffff
  lccs_class#flag_meanings=no_data cropland_rainfed cropland_rainfed_herbaceous_cover cropland_rainfed_tree_or_shrub_cover cropland_irrigated mosaic_cropland mosaic_natural_vegetation tree_broadleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed tree_broadleaved_deciduous_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed tree_needleleaved_evergreen_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed tree_needleleaved_deciduous_open tree_mixed mosaic_tree_and_shrub mosaic_herbaceous shrubland shrubland_evergreen shrubland_deciduous grassland lichens_and_mosses sparse_vegetation sparse_tree sparse_shrub sparse_herbaceous tree_cover_flooded_fresh_or_brakish_water tree_cover_flooded_saline_water shrub_or_herbaceous_cover_flooded urban bare_areas bare_areas_consolidated bare_areas_unconsolidated water snow_and_ice
  lccs_class#flag_values={0,10,11,12,20,30,40,50,60,61,62,70,71,72,80,81,82,90,100,110,120,121,122,130,140,150,151,152,153,160,170,180,190,200,201,202,210,220}
  lccs_class#long_name=Land cover class defined in LCCS
  lccs_class#standard_name=land_cover_lccs
  lccs_class#valid_max=220
  lccs_class#valid_min=1
  lon#axis=X
  lon#bounds=lon_bounds
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  lon#valid_max=180
  lon#valid_min=-180
  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=grid
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=copernicus-support@ecmwf.int
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#creation_date=20181130T105436Z
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_email=landcover-cci@uclouvain.be
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_name=UCLouvain
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_url=http://www.uclouvain.be/
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=-90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_resolution=0.002778
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_units=degrees_north
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=null
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=null
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_resolution=0.002778
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#history=lc-sr-1.0, lc-classification-1.0,lc-user-tools-3.14,lc-user-tools-4.3
  NC_GLOBAL#id=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.1.1
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=UCLouvain
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=land cover classification,satellite,observation
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords
  NC_GLOBAL#license=EC C3S Land cover Data Policy
  NC_GLOBAL#product_version=2.1.1
  NC_GLOBAL#project=EC C3S Land cover
  NC_GLOBAL#references=https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/
  NC_GLOBAL#source=PROBA-V
  NC_GLOBAL#spatial_resolution=300m
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Standard Names version 21
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=This dataset characterizes the land cover of a particular year (see time_coverage). The land cover was derived from the analysis of satellite data time series of the full period.
  NC_GLOBAL#TileSize=2025:2025
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_duration=P1Y
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=20161231
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_resolution=P1Y
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=20160101
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Land Cover Map of 2016
  NC_GLOBAL#tracking_id=1c3c8172-906d-4ce0-9aa7-f3a9d9b4e021
  NC_GLOBAL#type=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=16801
  time#axis=T
  time#bounds=time_bounds
  time#calendar=standard
  time#long_name=time
  time#standard_name=time
  time#units=days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,  -0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Metadata:
    ancillary_variables=processed_flag current_pixel_state observation_count change_count
    flag_colors=#ffff64 #ffff64 #ffff00 #aaf0f0 #dcf064 #c8c864 #006400 #00a000 #00a000 #aac800 #003c00 #003c00 #005000 #285000 #285000 #286400 #788200 #8ca000 #be9600 #966400 #966400 #966400 #ffb432 #ffdcd2 #ffebaf #ffc864 #ffd278 #ffebaf #00785a #009678 #00dc82 #c31400 #fff5d7 #dcdcdc #fff5d7 #0046c8 #ffffff
    flag_meanings=no_data cropland_rainfed cropland_rainfed_herbaceous_cover cropland_rainfed_tree_or_shrub_cover cropland_irrigated mosaic_cropland mosaic_natural_vegetation tree_broadleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed tree_broadleaved_deciduous_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed tree_needleleaved_evergreen_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed tree_needleleaved_deciduous_open tree_mixed mosaic_tree_and_shrub mosaic_herbaceous shrubland shrubland_evergreen shrubland_deciduous grassland lichens_and_mosses sparse_vegetation sparse_tree sparse_shrub sparse_herbaceous tree_cover_flooded_fresh_or_brakish_water tree_cover_flooded_saline_water shrub_or_herbaceous_cover_flooded urban bare_areas bare_areas_consolidated bare_areas_unconsolidated water snow_and_ice
    flag_values={0,10,11,12,20,30,40,50,60,61,62,70,71,72,80,81,82,90,100,110,120,121,122,130,140,150,151,152,153,160,170,180,190,200,201,202,210,220}
    long_name=Land cover class defined in LCCS
    NETCDF_DIM_time=16801
    NETCDF_VARNAME=lccs_class
    standard_name=land_cover_lccs
    valid_max=220
    valid_min=1
```

PS: I already checked following questions,

[Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: Please add gdalinfo report about C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2016-v2.tif.

Comment: I just added the gdalinfo report.

Comment: You have 129600x64800 pixels and if you read them into a single array it takes memory. And with your settings the output seems to be 64 bit that makes a lot more extra because the data type of the source is Byte, thus 8 bit. The way to limit the memory usage is to read, classify, and save result to disk as smaller chunks.

Comment: So can you please help me with how can I read it as an 8-bit array and implement it as your suggestion?

Comment: Consider using rasterio:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#blocks